# How do I trace library loading?

Tags: libraries

I have program that depends on library that is linked to libboost 1.67, which installed in the system. When I launch it, I have an error that `libboost_system.so.1.58` does not exist. `LD_PRELOAD` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` are unset.

`lddtree` execution doesn't show this library as dependency but `ldd` does.

How can I trace from where the library is required?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If on a GNU system, try running your application with:

```
LD_DEBUG=libs your-application
```

See `LD_DEBUG=help` for more options or `man ld.so`.

Comment: when I try LD_DEBUG=libs python3.6 on tcsh I get LD_DEBUG command not found. What is the tcsh alternative ?

Comment: @gansub prefix the command with `env` in tcsh

Answer (score 7):

If the program is loading libboost_system manually using dlopen(), you might be able to find where it is doing that using [ltrace](https://www.ltrace.org/) to see if it is calling dlopen(), and maybe gdb to set a breakpoint on calls to dlopen() and then generating a stack backtrace.  (See also [latrace](http://latrace.sourceforge.net/latrace.html).)